# Post request with form data to login to a website return 400 - Bad request

Tags: python-requests, request, postman, http-status-code-400

I am trying to login into [this website](https://auth.fiintrade.vn/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DStoxPlus.FiinTrade.SPA%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ffiintrade.vn%252Fsignin-callback%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520FiinTrade.Market%2520FiinTrade.Core%2520FiinTrade.Realtime%2520FiinTrade.Fundamental%26state%3D09092ea370e64626976fceeb55fb5ed5%26nonce%3Ddceb499c458e4af08f6e48f0668240ab%26clientType%3DWEBCLIENT%26fp%3D54404ac5041ff5b042c29fb397bef44d%26type%3Dredirect) with below credentials (no worry, it's anonymous):

> user = 'MattieBailey@mailinator.com'
> password = 'thx9jD3SkrssPKY'

When I logged in manually, I saw in Chrome inspector view there are sequentially a POST request and a GET request.

However, when I tried to simulate these requests with python, I got 400 - Bad request for the POST request. The GET request returned 200 - OK and sent me the content of the login webpage. In the Chrome Inspector View, all these 2 requests returned 302 status code with some response headers contains authorized id_token to use for further requests.

The same result was obtained when I tried to import these two requests to Postman so the problem might not be my code.

My ultimate goal is to get the id_token parameter in the response header of the GET request.

I appreciate your help!

#### POST request

```
curl 'https://auth.fiintrade.vn/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DStoxPlus.FiinTrade.SPA%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ffiintrade.vn%252Fsignin-callback%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520FiinTrade.Market%2520FiinTrade.Core%2520FiinTrade.Realtime%2520FiinTrade.Fundamental%26state%3D19e5bb5a7df14a2bab8ded1f265a7bda%26nonce%3D1547e70f8a2940b89dac75565e032046%26clientType%3DWEBCLIENT%26fp%3D54404ac5041ff5b042c29fb397bef44d%26type%3Dredirect' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'Origin: null' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,vi;q=0.8' \
  -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2...' \
  --data-raw 'ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DStoxPlus.FiinTrade.SPA%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ffiintrade.vn%252Fsignin-callback%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520FiinTrade.Market%2520FiinTrade.Core%2520FiinTrade.Realtime%2520FiinTrade.Fundamental%26state%3D19e5bb5a7df14a2bab8ded1f265a7bda%26nonce%3D1547e70f8a2940b89dac75565e032046%26clientType%3DWEBCLIENT%26fp%3D54404ac5041ff5b042c29fb397bef44d%26type%3Dredirect&Username=MattieBailey%40mailinator.com&Password=thx9jD3SkrssPKY&button=login&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8KNrfTjG6sBLmncBE9MMk0dDAX-OFwPXUy1uT0AqrEyhngGIImEM99JGxVKsssw62kRxLY2tHfTqfH8M8Mphqxh80YdwwHM6vpZIb-yVMnma4nS0QCkOf51FMFFu8pPwMM6FY52WEPSWy_ZWuaiAeCU' \
  --compressed
```

#### GET request

```
curl 'https://auth.fiintrade.vn/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=StoxPlus.FiinTrade.SPA&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ffiintrade.vn%2Fsignin-callback&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20FiinTrade.Market%20FiinTrade.Core%20FiinTrade.Realtime%20FiinTrade.Fundamental&state=19e5bb5a7df14a2bab8ded1f265a7bda&nonce=1547e70f8a2940b89dac75565e032046&clientType=WEBCLIENT&fp=54404ac5041ff5b042c29fb397bef44d&type=redirect' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,vi;q=0.8' \
  -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2...' \
  --compressed
```

#### Response header that contains id_token

```
Location: https://fiintrade.vn/signin-callback#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkY4MDA1REIxQkI0MzY4Q0Q3RkJFMUUxRTlEQjkwMTg2MUY5NEFGMTEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiItQUJkc2J0RGFNMV92aDRlbmJrQmhoLVVyeEUifQ.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.bObyB2sb-kkAxbxhhLc2hQsEtB6YAvzdtd2OwlLGKrzikqoGPwaQYlA41YK_v9OJLqUPRvKvkSZPBwfbguYXp8KnOAHxyPwM4lrbWc7u_OMIHarANxIsA50ckkj1gEszaGZtN6vtz4QYkxLMdbhHcpTnYd4XidFBVoyMQ3csLFaEifJEVsKfGStqgXW6etIhug5yuPnhjnZbCWdUPh0887auIuB_r7Nc7x6faHLtqr2in8c_TTKoI9YoM6LYBNkB7G7AtYkxlVImbyrdczHqsh6_ajLITuuSKYnwws2STwzPQMrZsIbHo_97ce3AVJcdUzVMXeY343FOYBDZeFteJg&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkY4MDA1REIxQkI0MzY4Q0Q3RkJFMUUxRTlEQjkwMTg2MUY5NEFGMTEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiItQUJkc2J0RGFNMV92aDRlbmJrQmhoLVVyeEUifQ.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.RSMsirz2etpYNVx9Pq1W1qExw1ETwCt5XUxglHwreyQX0WDZV3nUDOf5mxgNKjQx_sPCBQuF6SBH8IdNGcuv9ajvd2XbKWdcsNljXidiRHNGogo-JKIZIqadzLAEAmdXoYP_w2ToqOYkWmtEzm2SMpgbVzklRftciQg4h-K_jYW4YpteX23Az78yT3_RIirfBfszaTp5v3BEOR_StHG16bHPauOlIGmch6o6cWUSX1RPnqyAUVaNGELPygNQcmoYVgyQhwoloXyuDY7LGjhK3EgMm9iCuDx5JasFi5A0PQrAfgs1g7UftC-B_7XvJG4pw4qbevj3PehvZ9Kp1RshXw&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=28600&scope=openid%20FiinTrade.Market%20FiinTrade.Core%20FiinTrade.Realtime%20FiinTrade.Fundamental&state=19e5bb5a7df14a2bab8ded1f265a7bda&session_state=dV3zKwxom21hMpGaoJweGLKUlj2rO2gGSFWbw6bIw4U.ab1d0e2f49d55710dba656b0c958891d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out using Selenium. Here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

LOGIN_URL = 'https://auth.fiintrade.vn/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DStoxPlus.FiinTrade.SPA%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ffiintrade.vn%252Fsignin-callback%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520FiinTrade.Market%2520FiinTrade.Core%2520FiinTrade.Realtime%2520FiinTrade.Fundamental%26state%3Dd454e517f7ff44709a797670cd357be7%26nonce%3D890d02d7b58f42e88197818b035ad6d9%26clientType%3DWEBCLIENT%26fp%3De292f9093f0b9abc9904b5fba1d948c6%26type%3Dredirect'


def generate_token() -> bool:
    service = Service(cfg.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True  # do not show new window
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
    username_textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID, "exampleInputEmail1")
    username_textbox.send_keys(cfg.USERNAME)

    password_textbox = driver.find_element(By.ID, "exampleInputPassword1")
    password_textbox.send_keys(cfg.PASSWORD)

    login_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "button")
    login_button.click()
    assert 'access_token=' in driver.current_url, 'Failed to get access token'
    resp = driver.current_url
    # get token from resp
    resp = resp.split('access_token=')[1].split('&token_type=')
    id_token = resp[0]
    token_type = resp[1].split('&expires_in=')[0]
    auth_token = token_type + ' ' + id_token
    with open(cfg.AUTH_TOKEN_SAVE_PATH, 'w') as f:
        f.write(auth_token)
    return 0
```